# How do i handle file uploads in NestJs Microservice

Tags: javascript, node.js, microservices, nestjs, multer

Do do I handle file uploads in Nestjs Microservice?

Since microservice doesn't use http req @FileInterceptor or Multer will not work.
Even if there's a workaround I am unaware of it.

Kindly help

Comment: Could you write the code ? or the error you're facing ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a concept called [Hybrid Application](https://docs.nestjs.com/faq/hybrid-application)
in nest.js. Which enable you to listen for HTTP requests, as well as makes use of connected microservices.

something like this :

```js
// Create your regular nest application.
const app = await NestFactory.create(ApplicationModule);

// Then combine it with your microservice
const ms = app.connectMicroservice({
  transport: Transport.TCP,
  options: { host: '0.0.0.0', port: 6000 }
});

await app.startAllMicroservicesAsync();
await app.listen(3000);
```

Comment: Yaa i used this, but i wanted to know if we can send file via TCP in message patterns